# Online IDE/Compiler for C++/CLI

Tags: software-development, ide, web, compiler

I'm looking for an online IDE/compiler which supports C++/CLI. I've been hunting around and can't seem to find one:

- https://repl.it/
- https://ideone.com
- https://paiza.io/
- https://dotnetfiddle.net/

*Please feel free to move this to a more appropriate Stack Exchange site if Software Recommendations is not the right place for it*

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to find some service that supports MSVC and then compile with the [**`/clr` flag**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/clr-common-language-runtime-compilation?view=vs-2019). Of course other compilers may also work fine if they have C++/CLI frontend, but currently cl.exe is the only choice. Luckily [rextester](https://rextester.com/) does [have MSVC](https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) and can also **run .NET binaries**. Just add `/clr` to compile C++/CLI code. See demo:

[image: C++/CLI program in rextester]

### Update:

Unfortunately MSVC in rextester is no longer free. Now [you have to be a patron to use that](https://www.patreon.com/rextester)

---

If you just want to ***see the output assembly*** then things are much easier because you don't actually need the runtime environment, just a proper compiler. You can use [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), select one of the MSVC compilers then prepend `/EHa /clr` to the options and see. The `/EHa` is necessary to override the default `/EHs`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:53,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:53,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:53,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:53,startLineNumber:8),source:%27int+f1(int+i1,+int+i2)%0A%7B%0A++++return+i1*(i2+%2B+1)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+f2(int+input%5B%5D)%0A%7B%0A++++System::Console::WriteLine(f1(input%5B0%5D,+input%5B1%5D))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:65.99063962558502,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x64+msvc+v19.24%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:34.009360374414975,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_24_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/EHa+/clr%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:15),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x64+msvc+v19.24+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

[image: C++/CLI assembly output on Godbolt]

In fact Compiler Explorer supports running binary and also has wine but I don't know why the execute option was disabled for exe files